# On Formatting Android Studio unfolds Dart code in a Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in *Android Studio* while editing a *Dart* file in a *Flutter* project will **unfold my code**, i.e. functions, methods, `editor-fold`'s etc.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

On further investigation I actually found out that the **very last top-level fold** in the file **remains** folded (but not the inside of it), i.e. if a first level fold is unfolded, then the last fold in that region will remain, but not the folds inside of that fold region.

Still, very strange behavior. Can I actually prevent **all** folding changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug, you should report it [here in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I used "Reformat code with dartfmt" as a temporary workaround.

Unlike "reformat code", this doesn't change the folding/unfolding.

[image: dartfmt]